# removing javascript eventlisteners

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have this following javascript to activate sometime

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

but I am having troubles removing the event listener when some i do this

```
document.removeEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

the function removeEventListener doesnt seem to work. I did a little search on similar cases and unfortunately i cant find the solution. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are sending an anonymous function to the addEventListener call. Use a named function instead and send that to removeEventListener, like this:

```
function handleTouchMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

document.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
```

Otherwise, the way you were doing it, the function you sent to removeEventListener was a completely different function, even though it had the same contents.

Comment: Further reading on proper usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener

Comment: wow. thanks howard for this and for the explanation. i understand now. thanks also adreas for the article link

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the actual same function reference like this:

```
function handleTouch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouch, false);

document.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouch, false);
```

You can't use a second copy of a different anonymous function even if they have the same code in them.